# Can i install Rstudio in kali linux?

Tags: anaconda, rstudio, kali-linux

I have installed anaconda on my kali linux OS. I am getting Rstudio as an option to install on navigator but when I click on it, it just loads and there is no progress. I even used terminal to do so, but it just points out some problems and is unable to fix it. I can't even find an option on Rstudio website to install for kali linux OS.

Comment: hi kali is based on debian , so i would try the  rstudio-1.4.1106-amd64.deb.

Comment: sidenote: kali is a specialized distro for pentesting, if youre new to linux you might want to use a more "standard" distro (ubuntu/ mint...)  in the beginning before rushing into special distros (like gentoo , arch , etc). This will save you ALOT of headaches..

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command to install Rstudio on Kali linux:

```
sudo apt update<br>
sudo apt -y upgrade<br>
sudo apt -y install r-base<br>
wget https://download1.rstudio.org/desktop/debian9/x86_64/rstudio-1.2.5042-amd64.deb<br>
sudo apt install ./rstudio-1.2.5042-amd64.deb<br>
```

If you encounter any dependency problems, run:

```
sudo apt -f install

For starting Rstudio, run:<br>
$ rstudio
```

Source: https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-r-and-rstudio-on-ubuntu-debian-mint/